# Github API punch card data transformation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch, github-api

I want to create a graph that displays the information provided by the Github PunchCard in a similar way as [this python script](https://github.com/guanqun/git-punchcard-plot), but with JavaScript instead, using D3.js. I retrieve the information from the Github API [this way](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-number-of-commits-per-hour-in-each-day) using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/punch_card`

Right now I am stuck with how to modify the response to gather the data and classify it by day / hour, but apparently I cannot access the Array. My code, so far, is as follows:

```
const showGithubData = (user, repo) => {
    console.log(`Querying user  ${user} and repo ${repo}`);
    fetchPunchCard(repoUser.value, repoName.value).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);         
    })
};

const fetchPunchCard = async (username, repository) => {
   /*  GET / repos /: owner /: repo / stats / punch_card */
    const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repository}/stats/punch_card`;

    const api_call = await fetch(url);

    const data = await api_call.json();
    return { data }
};
```

I return the correct values but then I cannot access them, in the same function. If in showGithubData() I do console.log(res[0]) it says *undefined*, however, when doing console.log(res) I can see it returns an Array of Arrays(3), like this:

```
{data: Array(168)}
data: Array(168)
[0 … 99]
    0: Array(3)
        0: 0
        1: 0
        2: 0
      length: 3
      __proto__: Array(0)
    1: (3) [0, 1, 0]
    2: (3) [0, 2, 0]
```

I want to access all of this positions (0 is day, 1 is hour and 2 is number of commits) to create my charts, but I don't know why I can't.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: When you do `console.log(res)`, are you doing that directly into the console?

Comment: no, I just run the function and see what the console.log does, i don't call it from the console itself. I run it in a server (everything is working within a webpage)

Comment: Ah, ok; are you able to show the code where the successful `console.log` is happening?

Comment: Sorry @OliverRadini if I didn't explain myself. The functions above are the ones called. I have a button in a website with an eventListener, and after typing the user and the repo I want to retrieve the info from, the function showGithubData() is called. Inside of it is fetchPunchCard, that returns a response with an array of arrays (as displayed in the second code chunck). I want now to access this array and filter the information to organise it by day / hour to create a bar chart.

Comment: No need to apologise; thanks for clarifying that further. You mention, though, that "when doing console.log(res) I can see it returns an Array of Arrays(3)"; I was wondering where that call is made?

Comment: as you can see in the code above, the console.log(res) is called once the fetchPunchCard function has been executed, using its response. This happens inside of showGithubData, which is triggered by a button and takes two inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the object we see printed by a console.log is not exact.
When I encounter this problem (I can't find my a key that is supposed to be there and I see in a console.log), I follow this 2 steps:

1. **Print the type**: To ensure is a json object and not just a string, in this case, it was an objet: `console.log(typeof res);    > object`
2. **Print all keys of the object**: sometimes the actual key is not shown but is still there: `console.log(Object.keys(res));  > [ 'data' ]`

And as you can see, we found our solution with step number 2, the key to access all values is `data`, so in your case, to access those values we need to do `res.data`

IE: `console.log(res.data[0]);   > [ 0, 0, 0 ]`